# Call/Run Animation Every Time user Navigates to new Page

Tags: reactjs, gsap, reach-router

I have a Nav (functional) component that contains a simple animation using GSAP. It animates the first time the page loads. I would like it to animate every time user clicks on a different page (I'm using React [Reach Router](https://reach.tech/router) for page navigation)

I know with a class based component, I could possibly use `componentDidMount` method but how can I achieve this with a functional component? And I don't think `window.onload` will work since site isn't actually re-loading, but re-routed.

Here's the [code in question](https://codesandbox.io/s/gsap-navbar-2yss2)

Comment: Maybe GreenSock's article on [working with React and GSAP](https://greensock.com/react/) can help, especially the ["Route Animation Demo"](https://gsap-react-route-animation.stackblitz.io).

Comment: @ZachSaucier according to that demo, it seems like I would have to include the nav component in all pages. I'll tinker around some more. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working. I kept everything contained within the `Nav` component. There may be a better solution but for now, this works:

```
  // set variable show initially to false
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  // set show to true on click, then false again 
  const handleClick = () => {
    setShow(!show);
    setTimeout(function() {
      setShow(false);
    }, 500);
  };

  // if show is true, then run animation
  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      TweenMax.from(navbar.current, 1, {
        y: -105
      });
    }
  }, [show]);
```

Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gsap-navbar-2yss2).

Answer (score 0):

Include the `Nav` in the `Products` and `About` components.